# Primusrun/Optirun allegedly cannot locate/open config directory: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d"

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia, bumblebee

I have recently switched from open source drivers to nvidia, to `bumblebee` as instructed by ubuntuforums.org users to better use my two gpu's capabilities.
It also so happens that it does not seem to work at all, I keep getting this error regardless of which command I try.

Doing `ll /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d` I can see that this presumed config file is a directory, I am not too knowledgeable about this but I think it's correct provided the `.d` extension.

Full error:

```
optirun glxgears
[ 9546.928811] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Unable to locate/open config directory: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d"
```

```
primusrun glxgears
primus: fatal: Bumblebee daemon reported: error: [XORG] (EE) Unable to locate/open config directory: "/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d"
```

EDIT:
I didn't specify it but yes `xorg.conf.d` exists and if I try use `ll` on that directory my result is this:

```
ll /etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 jan  2 14:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 jun 18 22:55 ../
```

Comment: Does this method https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/1082#issuecomment-1058314581 work?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem with this command on Debian 11:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/X11/xorg.d/20-nvidia.conf /etc/bumblebee/20-nvidia.conf
```

I also had to install the following:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-mouse
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-kbd
```

Furthermore, I had to purge `xserver-xorg-legacy`:

```
sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-legacy
```

References:

- https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/issues/749#issuecomment-216352740
- https://debian-facile.org/doc:materiel:cartes-graphique:nvidia:optimus#erreur-d-identifiant-pci (in French)

Answer (score 0):

Turning off WiFi made the graphics card work.

Run `nmcli radio wifi off` and try `primusrun glxgears` or whatever you want to run on the GPU. If it works, you can turn WiFi on again and it should work as normal, and you can also continue to run new `primusrun whatever` commands so long as one primusrun remains running it seems.

Found this answer here, hope it helps: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=963980#77